# When I try to create create-react-app , it shows "npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

[image: npm error while creating react app]

I tried everything told on this platform till now, but of no avail. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: please do not post code images